# Retopolgy around eye holes

Tags: modeling

The mesh  needs retopologising, but I have the problem of the reotopologised mesh's eye holes not sticking to the edges of the eye holes in the original mesh. How can I fix this?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a small lip to the edge of the eyelid that your retopo is skipping through.  You are probably fine to just continue, retopo is generally for skipping detail like that.  If you want, you could capture that detail with a baked normal map.

If you are intent on modeling the small detail, I would add an edge loop in edit mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

It could the a subdivision modifier on the new mesh.

If so, then try selecting the new holes edge and play with the edge crease under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.